# Understanding HAL DBus Events?

Tags: dbus, hal

I'm watching HAL events on DBus, observing when the AC Adapter is removed / plugged-in.

Via *dbus-montior*, the two events appear the exact same:

**unplug event**

```
signal sender=:1.85 -> dest=(null destination) serial=3698 path=/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_power_supply_ac_adapter_AC0; interface=org.freedesktop.Hal.Device; member=PropertyModified
   int32 1
   array [
      struct {
         string "ac_adapter.present"
         boolean false
         boolean false
      }
   ]
```

**plug-in event**

```
signal sender=:1.85 -> dest=(null destination) serial=3701 path=/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_power_supply_ac_adapter_AC0; interface=org.freedesktop.Hal.Device; member=PropertyModified
   int32 1
   array [
      struct {
         string "ac_adapter.present"
         boolean false
         boolean false
      }
   ]
```

However, explicitly querying the *ac_adapter.present* property in *org.freedesktop.Hal* does correctly return the device state.

***The Question:*** What are the booleans sent in the PropertyModified event? Does there exist an event I can filter for that will contain information on the adapter's presence, or do I have to explicitly query after receiving the more nebulous 'something happened' message?

The [HAL DBus documentation](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dkukawka/hal-spec-git/0.5.11/hal-spec.html) was not particularly helpful, or I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I have to explicitly query after receiving the more nebulous 'something happened' message?

Yes. If you use a DBus browser like d-feet, you will see that the `org.freedesktop.Hal.Device` interface on the AC adapter object has methods

- `GetProperty(String property) -> Variant`
- `GetPropertyBoolean(String property) -> Boolean` - likely useful for `ac_adapter.present`